# Code from GeoGebra

Tags: compiling

I made a picture on GeoGebra and exported its code to Overleaf and then I compiled but it does not even show the pdf compilation. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(1.,-2.) rectangle (7.,2.5);
\fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (3.5529849861247715,1.6224751896453264) -- (2.1080515726119877,-0.9010704902924921) -- (6.208813302510944,-1.1452845883509906) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (3.5529849861247715,1.6224751896453264)-- (2.1080515726119877,-0.9010704902924921);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (2.1080515726119877,-0.9010704902924921)-- (6.208813302510944,-1.1452845883509906);
\draw [line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq] (6.208813302510944,-1.1452845883509906)-- (3.5529849861247715,1.6224751896453264);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff] (3.5529849861247715,1.6224751896453264) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (4.16860802498057,1.8361625254465128) node {$$\scalebox{1.5} {x_2}$$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (2.1080515726119877,-0.9010704902924921) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (2.2657731776081014,-1.0028263644835331) node {$$\scalebox{2}{x_1}$$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (6.208813302510944,-1.1452845883509906) circle (2.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geogebra produces bad Ti*k*Z code and it must be edited.

The first thing to do is always to remove the `\clip` instruction and the `scriptsize` pseudoenvironment.

Also `$$\scalebox{2}{x_2}$$` is wrong and should be fixed.

The ridiculous accuracies are better trimmed down to a couple of decimals and the position of the labels should be fixed.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
\fill[
  line width=2pt,
  color=zzttqq,
  fill=zzttqq,
  fill opacity=0.1
] (3.55,1.62) -- (2.11,-0.9) -- (6.21,-1.15) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (3.55,1.62)-- (2.11,-0.9);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (2.11,-0.9)-- (6.21,-1.15);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzttqq] (6.21,-1.15)-- (3.55,1.62);
\draw [fill=ududff] (3.55,1.62) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (3.55,1.9) node {$x_2$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (2.11,-0.9) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=ududff] (2.11,-1.2) node {$x_1$};
\draw [fill=ududff] (6.21,-1.15) circle (2.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask you one more question please? You see that the inner color of this triangle is not white. I am wondering what should I change to make it white?

Comment: @ZFR Replace `\fill` with `\draw`

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering can you take a look at my recent post please? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682647/space-between-definitions

Answer (score 2):

This may be off topic, but I don't know what advantage using GeoGebra has here. Define a style for your vertices and then just draw the triangle (and fill it, and label the vertices as nodes) with one `\draw` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,1}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, inner sep=1.7pt, outer sep=0, fill=ududff, draw=black, thin, label={[ududff]#1}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=2pt, color=zzttqq, fill=zzttqq!20] (3.55,1.62)node[vertex=above:$x_2$]{}
    -- (2.11,-0.9)node[vertex=below:$x_1$]{} -- (6.21,-1.15)node[vertex]{} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the lines

```
\draw[color=ududff] (4.16860802498057,1.8361625254465128) node {$$\scalebox{1.5} {x_2}$$};
```

and

```
\draw[color=ududff] (2.2657731776081014,-1.0028263644835331) node {$$\scalebox{2}{x_1}$$};
```

Replace them with

```
\draw[color=ududff] (4.16860802498057,1.8361625254465128) node {\scalebox{1.5}{$x_2$}};
```

and

```
\draw[color=ududff] (2.2657731776081014,-1.0028263644835331) node {\scalebox{2}{$x_1$}};
```

respectively.

Comment: There must be a reason why the developers of Geogebra decided to always add `\scriptsize` and then to scale up the labels, but I can't see it. Why one should be scaled by 1.5 and the other one by 2 is another mystery.